# How to Store a List Within a Model in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store a list within a model using Flask's SQLAlchemy library. The data stored would be a list of latitude longitude points like so:

```
['41.0282', '73.7787']
```

I would like to store a value like this inside my User table like the one below:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
```

Anyone know how I can go about this?

Comment: Add columns for longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to store a list in SQL. The proper way to handle multiple values is to create a new table and reference to that table with foreign keys.

If thats to heavyweight you can also store the values as a string and seperate them after your sql query.

This is then stored in your DB
    "41.0282, 73.7787"
To get your original list (python):

```
"41.0282, 73.7787".split(',')
```

Comment: That's not entirely true, Postgresql, for instance, supports arrays. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html