# flask-sqlalchemy how do I go about storing a list in a Model with a new table and foreign keys

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to add a list to a Model. I will need to be able to update the list in the future.
I saw an answer to the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013648/how-to-store-a-list-within-a-model-in-flask-sqlalchemy) where the person mentioned creating a new table and using foreign keys to reference it. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read here about foreign keys. https://medium.com/@auth0/sqlalchemy-orm-tutorial-for-python-developers-dbd0405673d1. very clear information.